# Containerized applications execute local script?

Tags: docker, go, nginx, ffmpeg, self-hosting

I'm trying to self hosted videos with nginx using nginx-rtmp-module (VOD) similar to youtube.

I successfully hosted videos by using ffmpeg to convert mp4 file to dash chunks.

I want my site can

1. upload video
2. Containerized golang app save file to local
3. run ffmpeg script to convert to dash chunks

How can I handle the third step ?

Is there a better way to make a VOD self hosted service ?

Comment: [os.exec](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec)

Comment: Are you trying to run a command outside the container on the host, or just run another command inside your container from your Go app? Or are you trying to execute commands from nginx? I'm not following the question/tags.

Comment: @BMitch I'm trying to run a command outside the container. I found out that I can execute commands with nginx using lua module but the installation is very difficult, I tried bunch of versions but always occur errors with luajit

Comment: That would be a container escape, you need to build your image with the commands you want to run inside the image.

Comment: @BMitch Is it possible to mount application from host to container.  I mounted ffmpeg to container when using docker-compose with `/usr/bin/ffmpeg:/usr/bin/ffmpeg` . I can see ffmpeg in `/usr/bin/` of container when exec that container. I run `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` but output not found

Comment: A not found error when you run the exact binary file that you can see with commands like ls is typically because of a missing dynamic linked library. You can see these with `ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg`. The goal of creating an image is to include the binary and all dependencies/libraries together in what you ship and run.

Answer (score 0):

> I run /usr/bin/ffmpeg but output not found

That is because the executable `ffmpeg` mounted from the host would depend on dynamic libraries either not present in the Docker image, or not at the right version (see [`ldd` or `lddtree`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120015/7490) for analysis)

It is better to build a dedicated image with the right tools installed in it rather than relying on the host content for program execution.